# How to upgrade Firefox on several computers on the network

Tags: networking, updates, firefox, remote-access

I have about 10 computers on my LAN and I would like to upgrade the Firefox on the computers across the LAN. The computers are not connected to the internet. I can download the tar files from the internet but it's almost impossible to go from system to system to install. Is their a way I can upgrade from the server?

Comment: Can you add detail. What was your '*wishlist*' of features and management capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not tar files, but debian packages.

I see following solutions:

- If one of the computers is connected to the Internet, you can use it as a local cache and point the package managers (apt) from other computers on the LAN to that machine
- If there is no other way than to install manually, use `pssh` or another parallel SSH solution (see [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/execute-commands-simultaneously-on-multiple-servers-using-psshcluster-sshmultixterm.html)). In essence, you connect to all computers using SSH, type a command, and the command gets executed on all machines.
- actually, it can be even achieved with a simple script if you can log in as root and using key-based authentication (this is not recommended in general, but could be OK on a LAN not connected to the Internet)

  ```
  for host in `cat hosts_to_update` ; do
       scp install_script.sh tar_file_blah.tar.gz root@$host
       ssh root@$host install_script.sh
  done
  ```

All of that will require some initial setting up, but afterwords you will be able to run the updates more smoothly.

Comment: There should be a proper solution, and Mozilla should be supporting it. I have looked at this issue before, but don't have an obvious solution to suggest. *I have done this manually, using SSH and limited scripting, but this still required some effort to force/update settings ..*

Comment: What "proper solution"? Distributing patches on 1.44" disks? :-) Come on, most people who use FF do have Internet access, or at least the computers have access to a server that can act as a proxy for autoupdates.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of classrooms, Internet Cafés, and small business. You need to be able to update, corral, and manage multiple desktops. Updates themselves can be automated.

Comment: Gee, there are plenty of tools for that, starting with rsync, through particular Debian / Ubuntu solutions such as apt-mirror and local caches, ending with much more powerful and general tools for administration of cloned systems such as [Puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) or [CFengine](http://cfengine.com/)-- but that *was not your question*! I thought you wrote "no Internet access" and you just wanted to update FF only?

Comment: Took a hiatus from here. Thanks all for the comments and directions. Will follow and comment back.